# MVC not returning json... request not available

Tags: mysql, json, spring

Hi all I want to return a userName with a rest http request in Spring + Mysql.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

     @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/userss/{userName}")
     public @ResponseBody String getUserName(@PathVariable String userName) {
        return userName;
     }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=8)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String status;


    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String emailAddress;


    @NotNull
    @Past
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }



    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }   
}
```

I just want to retrieve my services put,delete,post and get with requestmappings connecting with my model to my mysql DB. I´m trying to make the request in this way:
http://localhost:8080/portuzona/userss?userName=Arnoldo

But I get this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /portuzona/userss

type Status report

message /portuzona/userss

description The requested resource is not available.
```

portuzona and userss is correctly handled (html views) but I cannot make a get in my controllers.

Log says correctly the Table has been found by the bean:

```
sep 25, 2015 2:07:22 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: portuzona.users
sep 25, 2015 2:07:22 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [dateofbirth, password, firstname, emailaddress, id, username, lastname, status]
```

As a User requested here is more info that could be help .. or not:

/WEB-INF/servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>usersHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>usersHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

/WEB-INF/config/servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.portuzona" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're mixing up mapping and path variables. Two options:

1:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/userss/{userName}")
public @ResponseBody String getUname(@PathVariable String userName) {
   return userName;
}
```

http://localhost:8080/portuzona/userss/Arnoldo

2:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/userss/yourmapping")
public @ResponseBody String getUserName(@RequestParam String username) {
    return username;
}
```

http://localhost:8080/portuzona/userss/yourmapping?username=Arnoldo

Comment: Hi man, both ways brings me: type Status report

message /portuzona/userss/yourmapping

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Fixed my original post, sorry for the delay. Tested those options and either works fine.

Comment: No man, haha no luck here. Same result with both things... I think maybe is something about configuration... not sure... 

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/portuzona/userss?userName=Arnoldo
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: Can't help you without further information (e.g. portuzona mapping), please check it and post further code if necessary.

Comment: Where could be that? :O Pardon my ignorance

Comment: Looks fine to me, you don't even need any servlet information since you're not rendering a view but passing on a json response. Something must be off with the url you're trying to use. Can you post a working example from another of your controllers?

Comment: Ill pass you a link for the project soon... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with http://localhost:8080/portuzona/userss?userName=Arnoldo

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/userss")
public @ResponseBody String getUserName(@RequestParam String userName) {
   return userName;
}
```

Comment: Didnt work .... type Status report

message /portuzona/userss

description The requested resource is not available.